# why is my MySQL hostname empty ? and how to fix it?

Tags: mysql, hostname

so i wanted to know my hostname in MySQL but it giving me as an output `Empty set (0.00 sec)`

and i tried both :

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'hostname';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

and :

```
mysql> show variables like "%hostname%";
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Use `SELECT @@hostname;`

Comment: Your hostname is not empty, your mysql does not seem to have such a variable.

Comment: @Akina when i tried it, it gave me an error ```ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'hostname' ```

Comment: @Shadow oh so what does it mean?

Comment: Perhaps you have a version earlier than v5.0.38 installed - this is when this server variable was introduced.

Comment: @NadiaNadou If so then show the output of `SELECT VERSION();`

Comment: @Shadow oh you're right my version is : 5.0.15-nt

Comment: @Akina the output is : version: 5.0.15-nt

Comment: You really should install a newer version!

Comment: ok i will! thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these:

Especially see the syntax of SHOW variables

```
select @@hostname;
show variables where Variable_name like '%host%';
show variables where Variable_name like '%hostname%';
```

there is no variable for that in your Version

> hostname

> The server sets this variable to the server host name at startup. This variable was added in MySQL5.0.38.

Comment: I tried it, and it gives me the same thing:```                                                         Empty set (0.09 sec)```

Comment: in mysql8 all commands work, so please specify exactly which Version you are using mysql 5.x mysql 8 mariadb 10.x

Comment: I'm using mysql version: 5.0.15-nt

Comment: your Version doesn't support it. It is very very old and not longer supported, maybe it is time to start with a new Version(or upograde it, but i don't now of you find it anywhere

Comment: oh okay thank you so much, i will start using a newer version.